# Not able to use useBeamSchema for automatically converting Pcollection to table row schema

Tags: transform, google-cloud-dataflow

//Follwing code to readfile from GCS bucket, tranform and write to Bigquery

```
    PCollection<Quote> quotes = ...//get tranfrometed data 

     quotes.apply(BigQueryIO
         .<Quote>write()
         .to("my-project:my_dataset.my_table")
         .useBeamSchema()
         .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_`enter code here`TRUNCATE));

     //get error 
    //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to infer a coder and no Coder was //specified. Please set a coder by invoking Create.withCoder() explicitly  or a schema by invoking //Create.withSchema().
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to set a schema in your `PCollection`. Please see [example below.](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIOWriteTest.java#L271)